# body and content div height 100 in bootstrap 4 + angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to set `<div class="card">` center of page or body,
It work perfect on desktop browser but, in mobile view not work,
i can set it on center using...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #fc2c77 0%, #6c4079 100%);
}
```

and

**h-100,**

**align-items-center h-100**

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row align-items-center h-100 pt-5 pb-5">
    <form class="col-12 wow fadeInUp " data-wow-delay="0.2s">
      <div class="card"> 
       ...
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

it work perfect on desktop browser[image]

but in mobile view **form cut from top and bottom** and **body repeat at scroll**

[image]

Comment: Just because you have too much content... If your device is too small you can't do anything... But you can try to remove space between field to get the form more compact... but I don't know if it's a good idea for the design...

Comment: This is because you forced html and body to be exactly 100% of the viewport height. Don’t specify a height for those, remove the `h-100` class from the container element, and specify `min-height: 100vh` for it instead.

Comment: thanks for helping, misorude.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your form from cutting, add `display:table`, or `display:grid` to your parent .container:

`<div class="container h-100 "style="display:grid">...</div>`
or: 
`<div class="container h-100 d-table">...</div>`

Regarding the linear-gradient repeating at body scroll, make sure your `html` and `body` fill the page:

`body {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}`